# UNACCENT when checking for UNIQUE contraint violations in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, unaccent

We have a `UNIQUE` constraint on a table to prevent our `city_name` and `state_id` combinations from being duplicated. The problem we have found is that accents circumvent this.

**Example:**
`"Montréal" "Quebec"`
and
`"Montreal" "Quebec"`

We need a way to have the unique constraint run `UNACCENT()` and preferably wrap it in `LOWER()` as well for good measure. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to have two columns: first just to display which contains values like `"Montréal"` and second one for checks, indexing, searching, filtering etc which contains values like `"montreal"`...

Answer (score 1):

You can create an immutable version of `unaccent`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION noaccent(text) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
'SELECT unaccent(lower($1))';
```

and use that in a unique index on the column.

An alternative is to use a `BEGORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger that fills a new column with the unaccented value and put a unique constraint on that column.

Answer (score 0):

You can create unique indexes on expressions, see the Postgres manual:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/indexes-expressional.html

So in your case it could be something like

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_foo ON my_table ( UNACCENT(LOWER(city_name)), state_id )`

Comment: Should then also note that any queries wishing to make use of that index also have to filter on `unaccent(lower(city_name))` rather than just `city_name`

Comment: What about using something like a check instead of an index?

Comment: It's worth noting this will not be a heavy write table due to it's nature, mostly read.

Comment: Isn't unaccent only stable, meaning it can't be directly used in an index function?